# Getting “INTERNAL” exception when an async Firebase function is called from android app

Tags: android, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-functions

I’m trying to call an async Firebase function from android app and getting “INTERNAL” exception when the function returns.

Android:

```
 private Task<String> fetchData() {
    // Create the arguments to the callable function, which is just one string
    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put(“id”, “abc”);

    return FirebaseFunctions.getInstance()
            .getHttpsCallable(“calculate”)
            .call(data)
            .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, String>() {
                @Override
                public String then(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) throws Exception {
                    Map<String, Object> result = (Map<String, Object>) task.getResult().getData();
                    return (String)result.get(“data”);
                }
            });
 }
```

Firebase Function:

```
exports.calculate = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const text = data.id;
    return calc.calculate( (err, response) => {
        if(err) {
            // handle error
        } else {
            const data = response.dataValue;
        }
     }).then(() => {
        return {“data”: data};
     });
});
```

Exception:

```
com.google.firebase.functions.FirebaseFunctionsException: INTERNAL
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The documentation for [handling errors in callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors) indicates that an instance of [functions.https.HttpsError](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.https.HttpsError) must be returned:

> To ensure the client gets useful error details, return errors from a
>   callable by throwing (or returning a Promise rejected with) an
>   instance of `functions.https.HttpsError`... If an error other than
>   `HttpsError` is thrown from your functions, your client instead receives
>   an error with the message INTERNAL and the code internal.

It seems likely that your `calc.calculate()` call is returning an error that is not being handled correctly, resulting in a returned error status of INTERNAL.

Following the example in the document linked above, your code should be something like:

```
if(err) {
    // handle error
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('calc-error', 'some error message');
} else {
    const data = response.dataValue;
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue, it only happens when I call my function from an Android phone but on Windows Desktop Chrome it all works well. Anyway thanks "functions.https.HttpsError" tip. Should have read that part of the doc.

Comment: Note: The first argument, in the example above 'calc-error', must be one of the pre-approved error codes. 'calc-error' is not valid. The list of valid codes is here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_#functions-error-code

Answer (score 0):

When you call httpCallable ,you will get an **exception** called **FirebaseFunctionsExceptions**. You have to handled this exceptions. Wrap your code with **try** and **catch** .

***Example:-***

```
  try {
      final result = await FirebaseFunctions.instance
            .httpsCallable('deleteUser')
            .call({});
      } on FirebaseFunctionsException catch (error) {
        print(error.message);
      }
```

For more info follow this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors_on_the_client).